# (ValueError: unknown url type) while opening json (python3)

Tags: json, python-3.x, url

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl='https//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

while True:
    address=input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address)<1 :
        break
    url =serviceurl+urllib.parse.urlencode({'sensor':'false','address':address})
    print('retriving',url)
    uh=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data=uh.read().decode('utf8')
    print ('Retrieved',len(data),'characters')
    try:
        js=json.loads(str(data))


    except:
        json=None
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] !='OK' :
        print('fail~~')
        print(data)
        continue
    print(json.dumps(js,indent=4))
    lat=js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]['lat']
    lng=js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]['lng']
    print(lat,lat,lng,lng)
    print(location)
```

I am accessing the GeoJSON API of Google. The "uh=urllib.request.urlopen(url)" occurs error and can't open the url. What is the problem for my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `:` after the `https`:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
 HERE^
```

Comment: OMG I got this silly mistake. I think I may be blind. Btw thank you very much.